# Does rebinding an event do what it did before?

Tags: jquery

If I unbind() a handler in jQuery, when I "re-bind" will it still do what it did when it was originally bound?

Comment: I would think so, but wouldn't it be easier to try than to post a question here?

Comment: What do you mean? Execute the former `bind` handler that you `unbind`ed?

Comment: Yes, João. I did and results were inconclusive GolezTrol

Comment: @MB34: so please share your results

Comment: Why did the question Nazi's say this was vague and ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you unbind a specific handler , then it removes all the handler code that was bound to it..

$('#elem').unbind('click')
Removes the click event for the element
$('#elem').unbind()
Removes all the events attached to it..

When you rebind , yes it will give the same functionality provided you call the same function.. If you bind it to a different function then obviously it will give a different output..